# Why do casting rules differ between computers in python?

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I am running python 2.7 on my Mac, and I'm working on a group coding project with other people using Ubuntu. Every once and a while, code they write won't work on my computer due to casting rule errors:

```
    273     # Apply column averages to image
--> 274     img[:middle] *= (bg[0]/np.tile(topCol, (middle,1)))
    275     img[middle:] *= bg[1]/np.tile(botCol, (middle,1))
    276 

TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc multiply output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int16') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

I don't think you need the specifics, since this happens in a few different places with different number types.

It works on all of their computers no problem. Everything I write works for them, but every so often what they write doesn't work for me.

Is there a reason why our machines don't agree and is there a way I can change things on my end?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Python versions are you all running?

Comment: All running Python 2.7.3 I believe.

Comment: Are they running 32-bit builds of Python while you're running a 64-bit build? If so, if you don't specify types explicitly, `numpy` may make different guesses on each system. (Although the obvious problems would be `int64` vs. `int32`, not `float64` vs. `int16`…) Using explicit `dtype`s may solve the problem.

Comment: Also, which `numpy` versions are you each using? If you've done a `pip install numpy` while they've done an `aptitude install python-numpy`, they may be getting a version from months ago (one that was tested to fit in with the other packages from their version of Ubuntu), while you have the latest one.

Comment: Good question, we all got numpy from Enthought so it should be the same version. I'm checking on the python build and will update.

Comment: Does `img[middle:] = img[middle:] * bg[1]/np.tile(botCol, (middle,1))` also get a casting error?

Comment: these casting errors may be numpy version dependend, but I would be very surprised if they are architecture depenend (this one in itself certainly not). (though basically anyone should be using 1.6. right now probably, so it seems a bit odd). Of course they should not change too unexpected... But if you for example self compiled from the development version an update may fix most of it.

Comment: @jwpat7, `img[middle:] = img[middle:] * bg[1]/np.tile(botCol, (middle,1))` Does not get an error. So it works just fine.

Comment: @abarnert, I checked and I am using numpy 1.8.0, while they are using 1.7.#. More research seems to point to this as the problem. 1.8.0 has stricter type casting.

Comment: @zachd1_618: Wait… there's a 1.8.0? Didn't 1.7.0 just reach rc status this week?

Comment: @abarnert, I guess so! When I was (hopelessly) setting up Python, I remember I had to get edge versions of Numpy and Scipy in order to get the Pandas library to work on my Mac. So that could explain it.

Comment: @zachd1_618: Using Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7 on Lion or Mountain Lion, all I had to do was `sudo easy_install pip; sudo pip install --upgrade numpy scipy pandas`. (If you want Fortran support, you also need to install Homebrew and `brew install gfortran` first.) I don't know why everyone is still telling people to get third-party Python on Macs—great advice in the Tiger days, when Apple shipped an incomplete and 2-versions old Python, but that's not true today, and the advice just makes everything harder.

Comment: @abarnert: Alright I was pretty new at the time so I may have unintentionally messed with my python dist because I don't think that worked for me. But I can't fully remember now. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @zachd1_618: It's really not your fault at all. Most of the tutorials out there still start with "Apple's Python is years out of date and incomplete, so install another one", so naturally everyone follows that advice, and then they all come here asking for help when their two 2.7 installations are conflicting with each other. (If they just recommended installing 3.3 instead of 2.7, then it would be good advice again…)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This thread](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2012-September/063915.html) suggests that your `numpy` is newer than the version your colleagues are using (please check using `numpy.version.version`). In the 1.7.0 development branch, it seems they've changed the implicit casting rule to the more strict `same_kind` rule, which forbids (among other things) casts between floating-point and integer formats.

To work around this, I'd recommend using code like this:

```
img[:middle] *= (bg[0]/np.tile(topCol, (middle,1))).astype(img.dtype)
```

Comment: Yes, that is certainly the reason. 1.7. is basically released at this point, I would just suggest an upgrade (the change was reverted). Note however that casting as you suggested it is *not* the same thing for that you have to do the multiplication before the cast.

Comment: That is it, my numpy is newer than theirs is, which is where the problems arise. There are a few ways around the problem, but yours works

Answer (score 5):

nneonneo had a correct solution, I thought I'd add a few other work arounds.

One problem was that the `img` variable was manually defined earlier as an `int`. Then the multiplication with a `float` violated strict type casting

```
img = np.int16( cp.deepcopy(imgArray) )
...
img[:middle] *= bg[0]/np.tile(topCol, (middle,1))
>>TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc multiply output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int16') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

One work around:

I can change the initial variable type definition to match what is needed later:

```
img = np.float64( cp.deepcopy(imgArray) )
...
img[:middle] *= bg[0]/np.tile(topCol, (middle,1))
```

Or I can keep the original type casting, and change the operator:

```
img = np.int16( cp.deepcopy(imgArray) )
...
img[:middle] = img[:middle]*bg[0]/np.tile(topCol, (middle,1))
```

For some reason, Numpy allows the operation this way, where it wouldn't with `*=`

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

To quote the developers of numpy (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html):

> Default casting for inplace operations has changed to 'same_kind'. For instance, if n is an array of integers, and f is an array of floats, then n += f will result in a TypeError, whereas in previous Numpy versions the floats would be silently cast to ints. In the unlikely case that the example code is not an actual bug, it can be updated in a backward compatible way by rewriting it as np.add(n, f, out=n, casting='unsafe'). The old 'unsafe' default has been deprecated since Numpy 1.7.

Thus, if you want to keep the inplace multiplication, the code becomes:

`np.multiply(img[:middle], (bg[0]/np.tile(topCol, (middle,1))), out=img[:middle], casting='unsafe')`